# Symfony 3.4 "$authenticationUtils" argument

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

please i need help!!

This is my `security.yml` :

security:

```
encoders:
    UserBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
providers:
    db_provider:
        entity:
            class: UserBundle:User
            property: username 

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
```

my Controller  :

```
namespace UserBundle\Controller\Login;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
    {
//        return $this->render('@User\Login\login.html.twig');
        $errors = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
        return $this->render('@User\Login\login.html.twig',array(
            'errors'=>$errors,
            'username'=>$lastUsername,
        ));
    }
}
```

My View (login.html.twig):

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="panel panel-success" style="width: 500px;">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Login</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username : </label>
                    <input type="text" name="_username" id="username" class="form-control" value="{{ username }}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password : </label>
                    <input type="password" name="_password" id="password" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn-info btn pull-right">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        {% if errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{ errors.messageKey }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

The Error is :

> Controller "UserBundle\Controller\Login\LoginController::loginAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$authenticationUtils" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.

I tried searching i didn't figured where is the problem here even i already have another project that works fine with the same code

Comment: Guessing you did not tag your controller.  Compare the services.yaml file with the working app.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem, i didn't add UserBundle\Controller\ as you said,  Thanks man you save me :) (y)

Comment: I invite to use FosUserBundle http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/form_login_setup.html):

> If you get an error that the $authenticationUtils argument is missing,
>   it's probably because you need to activate this new feature in Symfony
>   3.4. See this [controller service argument note](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller.html#controller-service-arguments-tag).

Try to define this in your services.yml file:

```
UserBundle\Controller\Login:
        public: true
        bind:
            $authenticationUtils: '@security.authentication_utils'
```

Regards.